# Excluding HTML (Angular template files) from coverage reports

Tags: angular, jestjs

We are noticing that for an Angular application that has Jest testing configured, when generating coverage reports, the separate HTML template files for our components are being included in the coverage output.

For example:

[image]

**jest.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    displayName: 'f-assets',
    preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
            stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
            isolatedModules: true,

        },
    },
    coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/libs/f-assets',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
    },
    snapshotSerializers: [
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
    ],
    reporters: [
      'default'
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/(?!ngx-json-viewer|lodash-es)"
    ]
};
```

I have scanned the Jest config documentation and not come across what is required to get these files excluded, can someone suggest the correct approach here please?

BTW - we are using Angular 12 with Jest 26.0.24

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding
coveragePathIgnorePatterns : ['\.html$'],

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).